# Through terminal the user is asked to enter dimensions for a shape. Need to store details in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So this is my rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double perimeter;
    private double area;

    private static ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    public Rectangle(String name, double length, double width) {
        super(name, 4);
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.perimeter = getPerimeter();
        this.area = getArea();
    }   

    public static Rectangle addRectangle(String nameIn, int sidesIn, double lengthIn, double widthIn) {
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.setName(nameIn);
    rectangle.setNoOfSides(4);
    rectangle.setLength(lengthIn);
    rectangle.setWidth(widthIn);
    rectangle.setPerimeter(lengthIn,widthIn);
    rectangle.setArea(lengthIn,widthIn);
    rectangles.add(rectangle);
    return rectangle;
}
//getters and setters
```

main class:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(Strings[] args){
    String shapeNameInput;
    double rectLength;
    double rectWidth;

    System.out.println("Please enter a name for your rectangle");
    shapeNameInput = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the length of your rectangle");
    rectLength = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Please enter the width of your rectangle");
    rectWidth = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
```

I've instantiated an arraylist in my rectangle class but when i try to add to the arraylist, nothing seems to be working. Tried countless ways that i can't remember most of them..

I later need to convert the arraylist's contents to .json, should i do that before storing into the arraylist(if possible?) or not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the code that's adding to the arraylist?

Comment: sorry, added it now. last one i remember trying out...

Comment: Please share the definition of the `add` method

Comment: @Piyin what do you mean by share the definition of the add method?

Comment: You're calling `rectangle.add`, so `add` should be a method of the `Rectangle` class. Please share that method

Comment: I recommend that you go and talk to your teacher or tutor.  *"Tried countless ways that i can't remember most of them."*  This suggests me that you are taking the wrong approach to learning to program: see above.

Comment: @Piyin fixed the methods you mentioned. thanks for pointing that out. i'm still getting a warning under the parenthesis "Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();" -  'Rectangle() in Rectangle cannot be applied to .... '

Comment: @StephenC thanks for your support.

Comment: But I meant that seriously.  Your approach to learning to program is putting you at risk of failing your exams.  Talk to your teachers.

Comment: Isn't the `rectangles` list supposed to be in the program scope rather than the `Rectangle` one? I mean, a rectangle is supposed to have a list of rectangles inside?

Comment: "i try to add to the arraylist, nothing seems to be working" does not explain what is not working. ` rectangles.add(rectangle);` adds the newly created `rectangle` to `rectangles`